Interpolation between two Dataframes (years with values) in Pyspark
How can I implement linear interpolation between two PySpark DataFrames representing data for different years, say 2020 and 2030, to generate a new PySpark DataFrame for an intermediary year like 2025? Both DataFrames have identical structures with numeric values. The years have the same granularity.
My initial approach involved https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html
Is this the recommended way?
I have written this Pandas method awhile back, but I need to mgirate to Pyspark, but I struggle to implement the same in Pandas.
def interpolate_between_years(first: DataFrame, second: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:

    years = [first.index.year[0], second.index.year[0]]
    interpolated_df = (
        pd.concat(
            [first.reset_index(drop=True), second.reset_index(drop=True)],
            keys=years,
            axis=1,
        )
        .T.reindex(np.arange(years[0], years[1] + 1))
        .interpolate()
    )

    return interpolated_df


you can union those two dataframes to get a new dataframe. Order by the time column and then interpolate the values for inbetween rows. what did you find hard ?

I will try union before interpolating. Thanks.

You may use Pandas API on Spark PySpark as follows to do linear interpolation:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def interpolate_between_years(first: DataFrame, second: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    year_first = first.select("year").first()[0]
    year_second = second.select("year").first()[0]

    years_range = range(year_first, year_second + 1)
    interpolated_df = spark.createDataFrame([(year,) for year in years_range], ["year"])

    for col_name in first.columns:
        if col_name != "year":
            first_val = first.select(col_name).first()[0]
            second_val = second.select(col_name).first()[0]
            diff = second_val - first_val
            factor = (col("year") - year_first) / (year_second - year_first)
            interpolated_df = interpolated_df.withColumn(col_name, first_val + diff * factor)

    return interpolated_df

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data_2020 = [(2020, 10, 20), (2021, 11, 21), (2022, 12, 22)]
df_2020 = spark.createDataFrame(data_2020, ["year", "value1", "value2"])

data_2030 = [(2030, 40, 50), (2031, 41, 51), (2032, 42, 52)]
df_2030 = spark.createDataFrame(data_2030, ["year", "value1", "value2"])

interpolated_df = interpolate_between_years(df_2020, df_2030)
interpolated_df.show()

Output:
+----+------+------+
|year|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|2020|  10.0|  20.0|
|2021|  13.0|  23.0|
|2022|  16.0|  26.0|
|2023|  19.0|  29.0|
|2024|  22.0|  32.0|
|2025|  25.0|  35.0|
|2026|  28.0|  38.0|
|2027|  31.0|  41.0|
|2028|  34.0|  44.0|
|2029|  37.0|  47.0|
|2030|  40.0|  50.0|
+----+------+------+

From this interpolated_df, you may fetch data for any intermediary year like 2025, 2026, and so on.

I am sorry, but I do not need Pandas code. I want to interpolate using PySpark only.

@Pfinnn That's not Pandas. That's Pandas API on Spark. It's worth looking at for this type of work. You can check more about it here.

Thanks Vikas. But my goal is to implement this entirely in spark native, without the pandas on spark api.

@Pfinnn I have updated the code as per your requirement. It's now entirely written in PySpark.
